# Updating SharePoint field links

Tags: list, sharepoint, contenttype

I used a piece of code that retrieves a field link for a specified content type and sets the field to either required or not required. This works fine but when I try to do the same for a field that has spaces in the name, the code throws an error.

```
SPField col = //some column retrieved from a list
SPContentType ct = col.ParentList.ContentTypes["MyContentTypeName"] //gets the content type

SPFieldLink fieldLink = ct.FieldLinks["MyFieldname"]; // gets the fieldLink
ct.Update();
```

It works if `MyFieldName` is a string like "Hobbies" or "Amount", but fails if it's a string like "Full Name".

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: For anyone relying on the code shown in the question, note that SPFieldLink does not have an Update method as suggested. The code should show ct.Update, not fieldLink.Update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the field display name instead of the field internal name

Have you tried: 
    "Full_x0020_Name" ?